# Excel formula on IF

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a IF formula with 3 conditions. Request for help.

Conditions:

If Cell value is less than 10000 the value should be 0
If cell value is greater than 10000 and less than 15000, the value should be 150
if the cell value is greater than 15000, the value should be 200.

I am trying the below formula but for cell value less than 10000, The value is showing as "false"

```
=IF(cell>10000<15000,150,IF(cell>15000,200,0))
```

Comment: -1, no research effort

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want

```
=IF(A1<10000,0,IF(AND(A1>10000,A1<15000),150,IF(A1>15000,200)))
```

However, your logic is possibly (*probably*) flawed. What happens if the value is 10000 or 15000?

You don't ask for this to be catered for, so I left Excel to treat it as it wants to (by default will enter the word False for this)

Answer (score 0):

Dave is right. If you want to deal with values 10k or 15k here is a slightly simpler formula where both boundary (not sure if this is the right word) values are always considered to be in higher interval

```
=IF(A1<10000,0,IF(A1<15000,150,200))
```

Therefore you have following intervals

```
(-infinity, 10000) - value 0
<10000, 15000) - value 150
<15000, infinity) - value 200
```